# VBA Activate Userform Tab depending on active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, userform, multipage

I have a userform with a number of tabs that relate to specific worksheets. I’m trying to activate a specific tab depending on what the active worksheet is when the userform is initialized. Can someone help me out here.

Thanks.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Test1" Then
    MultiPageSheets.SelectedItem.Index = 0

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Test2" Then
    MultiPageSheets.SelectedItem.Index = 1

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Test3" Then
    MultiPageSheets.SelectedItem.Index = 2

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Test4" Then
    MultiPageSheets.SelectedItem.Index = 3

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe it's just `Multipage.Value = X` rather than `Multipage.SelectedItem.Index = X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Test1" Then
    MultiPageSheets.Value = 0

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Test2" Then
    MultiPageSheets.Value = 1

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Test3" Then
    MultiPageSheets.Value = 2

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Test4" Then
    MultiPageSheets.Value = 3

End If

End Sub
```